# Memory leak when using array list

Tags: java, memory, arraylist, memory-leaks

I am executing the below program and storing the value in-memory object, but GC is not able to clear the object memory resulting in the out of memory exception

Kindly assist with your insight

```
package sampletest;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class studentDB
{
  public static List<Student> retrieve()
    throws ParseException
  {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setAge(new Integer(i));
      student.setBirthDate(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse("01061986"));
      student.setName("Student" + new String(new Integer(i).toString()));
      students.add(student);
    }
    return students;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: "*[...] but GC is not able to clear the object memory [...]*" - As long as you hold a reference to the `List` and do not remove elements from said `List`, why should the GC clear the object? How do you use the returned `List`?

Comment: GC can`t clear memory of in use variable.

Comment: Whats the point of this question? Do you really ask "I create a lot of object (for whatever reasons) and return them to use them later, but I want GC to remove them". What's the point in creating these objects when you obviously don't care about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a memory leak - you are just using too much memory.

This is why `List` is an interface - so you can build your own `List`s. This one builds your `Student`s on-the-fly.

```
public static List<Student> retrieve() {
    return new AbstractList<Student>(){

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return MAX_STUDENTS;
        }

        @Override
        public Student get(int index) {
            // Make each student on demand.
            Student student = new Student();
            student.setAge(new Integer(index));
            // Date parsing removed because that just untidys the demo.
            student.setName("Student" + index);
            return student;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you return the `List<Student> students`.

When you call this method, you will get a reference of this list object. You must release the reference, or it will never be cleared by GC.

Of course, if the list is too big, and your memory is not enough to contain it, here will also throw the out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you are trying to emulate a database call and provide a Stub functionality for test purposes. As stated by others its not the issue with the code, but the amount of heap being assigned. Try changing the Xmx args to an higher value and check if it works for you.